# Alternatives to checks for rental payments. Bank account transfer

Tags: united-states, check, ach

I have a tenant who would prefer not to write and mail checks each month,
and I'd rather not have to cash them.

What are the options for "bill pay" like electronic checks/ACH services between individuals?  I know the tenant can use "bill pay", but that results in a paper check I then have to cash.  We use different banks in the same city.

Oh yes, this the United States of America, where I can't just "do this". It's never been supported.

Comment: Simple - Electronic Funds Transfer (EFT) from his account to yours.

Comment: Why can't you simply use bank transfer? Don't you have a bank account?

Comment: Both sides have bank accounts.  This is the USA, there's no culture or support for such transfers between individuals.

Comment: @Bryce:  But there is.  I pay my friend my share of our horse expenses with an electronic transfer.  We do bank at the same credit union, but if I'm reading the site's info correctly, I should be able to do it with any bank account.

Comment: @jamesqf in the USA there's a clearinghouse for checks and epayments, known as ACH.  In theory it's possible, but in practice the banks here just don't do it.  If your credit union really does it, great.

Answer (score 4):

My bank recently began to implement a service known as [Zelle](https://www.zellepay.com/). If the sender of the money has a bank on the Zelle client list, it can be used to transfer funds at no cost to other parties, based on an email address or telephone number. I've recently performed a transfer of a substantial amount to a friend and had no charges or fees added. The web site says money can be sent to anyone with a bank account, which implies the recipient does not have to have a bank which supports the service, but the sender will, obviously.

Comment: It works with most banks, if an email address is associated with your account.

Comment: I was about to answer with a service called PopMoney, which seems similar to your Zelle, and when I searched for my bank's reference, Zelle came up, [Citizens Bank Zelle page](https://www.citizensbank.com/learning/what-is-zelle.aspx). There seem to be a good number of such payment systems as I search further. a +1 for you.

Comment: My bank also supports PopMoney, but it carries a one dollar US charge that I have to pay, making it somewhat less desirable. I haven't checked, but I would not be surprised to learn that that particular service is dropped.

Comment: Dang, neither side supports it, Union Bank and Mechanic's Bank CA.

Comment: PayPal is the same concept. I've given money to friends and relatives with PayPal.

Comment: The disadvantage with paypal is the requirement for both parties to be registered with paypal. That can be considered tedious and some find it to be one more security weakness to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

> but that results in a paper check I then have to cash.

In addition to fred_dot_u's excellent answer about Zelle, most banks now have cell phone apps which allow you to endorse the check and then take a photo of both sides of the check.  Viola, it's deposited without you having to go near a branch.

Comment: :-) nice answer. But I'm a computer guy, no way I'm going to ever put a banking app on my phone that I carry with me.  I do scan checks for online deposit with the old Ing Direct / Capital One 360.

Comment: @Bryce suit yourself.  I'm a computer guy, and think it's better than sliced bread.

Comment: I reached my threshold of hacks and data breaches.  Enjoy your banking app.